# Problem using sendmail activity in workflow sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, lotus-notes, sendmail

I have a breakline problem using sendmail activity in a Sharepoint VS workflow.
I use      < br/ >      for the breakline, everything is ok in live mail&outlook but when i try it in lotus note all my text is inline.
How can i fix this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Hate to say it, but you probably can't 'fix' the problem.  It sounds like just an HTML rendering bug in Lotus Notes.  It doesn't sound like you're doing anything wrong in your HTML if it renders OK in other clients.

You might try changing your HTML code to find something that looks satisfactory in all clients, though.  Perhaps add a second `<BR />` or use a `<P>` instead?

Comment: yeah i will try to use <p> instead of <br/>, by the way i think that the problem come from Lotus Notes too...